Auto Login to WINS in Batch File using iSeries
This one is difficult to find information for as the product is no longer Produced.  IBM had a product called WINS that ran on the iSeries and connected to the AS400.  My company still uses it and we do a lot of our business out of it.  We have a long term plan to migrate off of it but it will probably take over 10 years.
I am trying to find a solution for something we do often.  We use batch files to tranfer data out of WINS which works great instead of having to run each file individually.  The issue is a user needs to log into WINS prior to being able to start the transfers.  I am trying to see if anyone knows a way to login within a batch file prior to starting the Transfer process.  This way we can automate the downloads.
Here is a sample of the bat file code:
C:\Users\%myuser%\IBM\ClientSolutions\Start_Programs\Windows_x86-64\acslaunch_win-64.exe /plugin=download \\FilePath\FileName.dtfx >> \\FilePath\clm_Annual_%mydate%_Log.txt

We do that same line of code for each file name and just repeat it for each transfer.
My ask is simply can we log into the iSeries in the batch file prior to running the transfers, so we can run it on a schedule.

I know of nothing from IBM for the IBM i/iSeries/AS-400 named WINS
The only thing I've every heard of named WINS is Microsoft's Windows Internet Naming Service.
It would appear that you're using the modern IBM Access Client Solutions (ACS) product.  In order to by-pass the GUI logon, simply Add the following to your batch file prior to the first download..
acslaunch_win-64.exe /plugin=logon /SYSTEM=MYSYSTEM userid=johndoe /PASSWORD=havingfun /AUTH /C /GUI=0

The parameters for the logon plugin are as follows

/SYSTEM - name of system
/USERID - user id
/PASSWORD - password associated with the user id
/AUTH - attempts connect to system with specified logon credentials - and only caches them on success
/C - clears the cache
/GUI - whether or not a graphical user interface
can be used


Charles I am going to test now.  two questions.

Is there a way to log out also?
is there a resource that I can find all of these commands?


@djblois the Getting Started guide contains information about the available plugin commands.  Using /plugin=logon /C would clear the auth cache; thus you'd have to log back in.
